# Custom clean() error on a Model and non_field_errors for inlineformset_factory

Tags: django

I have an Address model like so;

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=Address_Type, default=1, editable=False)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    pcode = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="AU", editable=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return '%s' % (self.user)

    def clean(self):
        if self.id:
            if self.type == 1 and self.street == '':
                raise ValidationError({NON_FIELD_ERRORS: ["Contact Address street must not me empty"]})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Address'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Addresses'
```

And using the following;

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, new = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
        addr, new = Address.objects.get_or_create(user=profile,type=1)
        addr, new = Address.objects.get_or_create(user=profile,type=2)
```

to create a profile and 2 blank address records for the user.

In my forms.py I have;

```
AddressFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Profile, Address, can_delete=False, extra=0)
```

and my view;

```
def CustomerProfileView(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('customer_login_view')

    template_name='customers/customer_detail.html'
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST, instance=profile, prefix='customer')
        addr_set = AddressFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid() and addr_set.is_valid():
            form.save()
            addr_set.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('summary_details')

    form = CustomerForm(instance=profile, prefix='customer')
    addr_set = CustomerFormSet(instance=profile)
    ctx = {'form': form, 'addr_set': addr_set}
    return render_to_response(template_name, ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and a snippet from my template;

```
{% for form in addr_set.forms %}
                {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                {% if forloop.first %}<h3>Contact Address</h3>{% else %}<h3>Shipping Address</h3><p><i>If different form contact address.</i></p>{% endif %}
                <table border="0">
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {% if not field.is_hidden %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ field.label_tag }}:</td>
                                <td>
                                    {{ field }}<br />{{ form.non_field_errors }}
                                    {% for error in field.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% else %}<td valign="bottom">{{ field }}</td>{% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </table>
            {% endfor %}
```

What I am trying to go is have 2 address records created automatically when a user registers but to have validation on a certain type of address and only on UPDATE, in this case the users normal contact address, the other type is for shipping and is optional. I suppose I could of flattened the tables or separated the different types into their own model but I decided to go down this path.

The clean() function in the Address model is working as far as it raises the error but I can't get that error to show in my template using non_field_errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some consideration of the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Contact Address and Shipping Address are two different concerns that probably merit different treatment, maybe even different persistence schema depending on your business requirements.  In this system you have lumped them into the same model. It's the 'type' field that raises the red flag for me.  You might as well have two models and eliminate the need to deal with different validation requirements from within the same model, which is the reason for your question.  At that point there are other [address validation concerns to consider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_Address_Verification)...

By the way, I develop software for an address verification company, [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com).  Let me know if you have any further questions or comments.